# Python flask for loop doesn't print all of the outputs?

Tags: python, flask

I have a dataset like this here:

```
df=    
    A            B            C
    house        50           50
    money        80           50
    bed          20           60
```

And this is my code:

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST'
        inpt = request.form['inpt']
  
        for text in df['A']:
            if text == inpt:
                give_text = df[df['A'] == inpt]
                give_text = give_text.drop(['A'], axis =1)

        for column in give_text:
            column_edit = give_text[column]
            column_edit = column_edit * 5
            
            return render_template('index.html', numbers = column_edit)
```

And how would it change if this is my code:

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST'
        inpt = request.form['inpt']
  
        for text in df['A']:
            if text == inpt:
                give_text = df[df['A'] == inpt]
                give_text = give_text.drop(['A'], axis =1)

        for column in give_text:
            column_edit = give_text[column]
            column_edit = column_edit * 5
           
            if ".." in column_edit:     #nvm which symbol
                column_edit = column_edit + "meters"
                return render_template('index.html', numbers = column_edit)
```

And my code on my HTML file:

```
<form> action ='/index' method = 'post'>
    <p>< input type = 'text' name='inpt'/> </p>
    <p>< input type = 'submit' name='submit'/> </p>
    
  
    <h3>{{numbers}}</h3>
</form>
```

**But why he is always printing on my website only the first anwser of my loop?**

If I write **'house**' for the **input**.
I wanted to print the whole calculated dataset on my website like this:

```
output:
    250
    250
```

Comment: `column_edit` is a `DataFrame` containing integers. `".." in column_edit` is not going to true ever. What is the exact criterion for adding `" meters"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `numbers` is an iterable, you may not be able to output it in html the way you've done. You may do this:

> Python-Flask

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST'
        inpt = request.form['inpt']

        for text in df['A']:
            if text == inpt:
                give_text = df[df['A'] == inpt]
                give_text = give_text.drop(['A'], axis =1)
        my_data = []
        for column in give_text:
            column_edit = give_text[column]
            column_edit = column_edit * 5
            my_data.append(column_edit)
            
        length = list(range(0, len(my_data))) #create a list for length of items in  column_edit, this list will server as indicies for iteration through elements of column_edit
     return render_template('index.html', numbers = my_data, length=length)
```

> HTML

```
<form> action ='/index' method = 'post'>
<p>< input type = 'text' name='inpt'/> </p>
<p>< input type = 'submit' name='submit'/> </p>
{% for i in blenr %}
<h3>{{numbers[i]}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do I always have to save the values ​​from the For loop in a list?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
another question. If I now set an if statement within the for loop? I edited my question (you can see the code there)

Comment: Just go ahead to append your value to the list after the operation within the condition done. But if you want to keep the value of column_edit before and after you if condition, you may need an additional list, to store the second set of values. In case you don't understand this explanation, you may update you question to reflect the additional 'if' statement block, and I'll update this answer to suit it.

Comment: It's not mandatory to always store values generated from a iteration in a list, but you must understand that after every iteration, the previous result is forgotten, and if you try to return like Fabrice Fabiyi advice, you get only the last result of the iteration. But, if you push the result of each iteration into a list, you may access all the result even after the iteration is done. You may use some other elements (aside list) of python data structure to store values, or even write your result to a file (flat or CSV). It all depends on what you want to achieve, when, and how.

Comment: Hey, is it now possible to access individual values ​​from this list instead of all values ​​in this list?

I've tried {{numbers [10]}}, but I always get an undefined error when refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

We must put the `return` outside the loop

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['POST'])
def index():
if request.method == 'POST'
    inpt = request.form['inpt']
    for text in df['A']:
        if text == inpt:
            give_text = df[df['A'] == inpt]
            give_text = give_text.drop(['A'], axis =1)

    numbers_list = []
    column_list_with_some_text = []
    for column in give_text:
        column_edit = give_text[column]
        
        if "some text" in column_edit: 
            column_list_with_some_text.append(column_edit + "There was some text")

        column_edit = column_edit * 5
        numbers_list.append(column_edit)
        
return render_template('index.html', numbers= numbers_list, column_list_with_some_text= column_list_with_some_text )
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the anwser!
What should I do, if I have also an if-statement inside the last for loop? Something like this:

if "some text" in column_edit:
     column_edit = column_edit + "There was some text"

where do i write the return then?

Comment: In the OP, the template only gets passed the first number, now it only gets passed the last.